# CanActivate guard in Angular providing delayed response

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a CanActivate guard to project a few routes based on login status. Though it is doing its job fine, the target component that I am protecting is shown for a second before the guard redirects me to the login page if I am not logged in. The guard doesn't have any HTTP calls or async running code. it is just checking data from a variable present in another service. Please suggest what all could be the reasons for such unexpected behavior.

Comment: Please add all relevant code, otherwise you're asking people to guess at what the problem might be

Comment: Are you adding you guard in you router?

Comment: If AuthGuard is implemented right, will block the component rendering until it's canActivate value is evaluated. Please provide a working example in StackBlitz for your problem, so we can help you with the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As you guys said Guard is working properly as it is properly implemented. The content which was flickering for a moment is coming from CMS who is not controlled by Guard. It was handled with a workaround